# Unity container resolve with partial classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am facing an issue when I use Unity to inject a dependency with two partial classes.  This is what I have done:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : IMyDbContext
{
    // code
}

public partial class MyDbContext : IMyDbContext
{
     // code
}

public interface IMyDbContext
{
    // code
}

var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IMyDbContext,      
MyDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

Using the above code, I get an exception about my db is null.  But, If I remove one partial class, so I will have only one partial class, all works fine.  I would very appreacite if you could you please on this.

EDIT:
When I in debug mode, the Unit container GetService method catches an exception ResolutionFailedException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by registering the instance and not the type.
However, any other solutions are welcome.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext()
container.RegisterInstance<IMyDbContext>(context);
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of the interfaces. One of the partial classes implements it so the other one can't. Remember that the partial class is compiled together in a single class so you can't have both partials implement the same interface because once combined, it is unknown which partial is actually implementing it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  If you mean to remove the interface from one partial class I already try it but still doesn't work.